# How to format sql_last_value in logstash in the config file

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

in input jdbc

```
input {
 jdbc {
   *jdbc driver and connection details*
  statement => "Select * from company_table where modified_dt > :sql_last_value"
  last_run_metadata_path => "c/es/timestamp_company.txt"
 }
}
```

Is there a way I can format the value in the :sql_last_value

The db date granularity is seconds and logstash timestamp is milliseconds. Due to this the data is not getting indexed sometimes.